# Checking if matrices in $ SU(2) $ generate an $ S $-arithmetic group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, gap

I am reading [Super-Golden-Gates for $PU(2)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02106) by Ori Parzanchevski and Peter Sarnak. If I understand correctly then in section 4.1.3 they seem to be saying that the matrices
$$
 F:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ i & -i \end{bmatrix}, S:=\zeta_8^7 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix}, \tau_{24}:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-10+2\sqrt{2}}} \begin{bmatrix} -1-\sqrt{2} & 2-\sqrt{2}+i\\ 2-\sqrt{2}-i & 1+\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}
$$
generate an S-arithemtic group. And in section 4.1.4 they seem to be saying that the matrices
$$
 F:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ i & -i \end{bmatrix}, \Phi:=\frac{i}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \phi-i/\phi \\ \phi+i/ \phi & -1 \end{bmatrix}, \tau_{60}:= \frac{i}{\sqrt{7+5\phi}} \begin{bmatrix} 2+\phi & 1-i\\ 1+i & -2-\phi \end{bmatrix}
$$
also generate an $ S $-arithmetic group (here $ \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $ denotes the golden ratio).

In general is there a good way to check if a given set of matrices generates an $ S $-arithmetic group?

That is, let $ g_1, \dots, g_k $ be finite order matrices in $ SU(2) $. Is there any easy way to check if the group they generate $ \Gamma:= <g_1, \dots, g_k> $ is an $ S $-arithmetic group?

It is a necessary condition that $ \Gamma $ should be infinite and moreover dense in $ SU(2) $. Are there any other necessary conditions that are easy to check?

Is there some way in GAP or Sage to check if a given set of finite order matrices generates an $ S $-arithmetic group?

Comment: Are you aware of the literature on finite generation and finite presentability of $S$-arithmetic groups? See for example [this MathOverflow question and its comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311596/are-finite-presentations-of-arithmetic-groups-computable).

Comment: An S-arithmetic group does not "live" in $SU(2)$. Instead you should consider a product with several p-adic groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok I think I've eliminated the incorrect terminology

Comment: Hmm... anyway, I think not only there is no easy way to check this but the problem is undecidable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan In this https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.16120 more recent paper of Shai Evra and Ori Parzanchevski the phrase "generate a full S-arithmetic subgroup of PU(2)/PU(3)" is used in the abstract and several times in the text. Do you have a sense of what he means? Is he using terminology loosely/ incorrectly? update: Ah well I am a beginner so I guess I'll stick to proper terminology!

Comment: Here is an example of an undecidable problem in a closely related setting: Consider a finite subset of $SL(2,Z)\times SL(2,Z)$. Does this subset generate a finite index subgroup (i.e. a sublattice)? This turns out to be undecidable.

Comment: Yes, this is a sloppy terminology (and I understand the meaning since I am familiar with the field). For a beginner, it is best to use the proper terminology.

Comment: As for references to the existing software, I would ping Alexander Hulpke, he is the true expert on these matters.

Comment: Typically testing density is easy, and testing arithmeticity hard. There is no ready-made command for doing so and algorithmic tests basically convert tio a finitely presented group and prove finite index. For doing this you would need a presentation for SU(2,R) (where R is your ring) and express the matrices as words in generators. I have done so for SL and Sp, never tried SU.